# databricks/R ---- Error: Max iterations (100) reached for batch Resolution

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks

I'm working on databricks and using R (I'm new with databricks). I encountered this error:

*org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Max iterations (100) reached for batch Resolution, please set 'spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations' to a larger value*

Could you help to increase the max iteration? How to change spark SQL config?

I've used the following command:

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations", "500")`

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: try `spark.sql("set spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations = 500")`?

Comment: did it work ?, setting spark.sql("set spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations = 500") did not  work for me

Comment: This has been fixed, some configs needs to be set while creating the cluster in databricks, so while creating the cluster *advanced options -> spark -> spark config*    here set the below configs                                                 
 spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations 10000
spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations 10000